# ASP.NET Identity: Additional properties to ApplicationUserRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have added an additional property to **ApplicationUserRole** as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
    {
        public string RoleAssigner { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i am to assign a role to an user as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserRoleViewModel userRoleViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var userRole = new ApplicationUserRole
                {
                    UserId = userRoleViewModel.UserId,
                    RoleId = userRoleViewModel.RoleId,
                    RoleAssigner = userRoleViewModel.RoleAssigner
                };
                context.ApplicationUserRoles.Add(userRole);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }               
        }
        return View(userRoleViewModel);
    }
```

**This is working fine!!**

Before adding additional "RoleAssigner" Property, I can assign a role to an user using ***AddToRoles()*** Method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserRoleViewModel userRoleViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {      
             UserManager.AddToRoles(userRoleViewModel.Id,   userRoleViewModel.RoleName);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }

        return View(userRoleViewModel);
    }
```

**My question is:** After adding an additional Property like "RoleAssigner", Is there any way to assign a role to an user using ***AddToRoles()*** method which will also insert the additional **"RoleAssigner"** value for **"RoleAssigner"** column in the database also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit with working example:*

I think you can do that by creating an extension method at IdentityConfig. 
I did something similar to find user by username or phone number

In what I'm able to understand you want to call UserManager.AddToRoles(...) and 
fill the new role property.

to do that( in similar to the example before ) you need an extension to user manager. you do it like this:

```
public static class UserManagerExtens
{
    public static IdentityResult AddToRole(this ApplicationUserManager userManager,string userId,string[] roles,string assigner)
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationUserRole role = null;
            using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                foreach (var item in roles)
                {
                    role = new ApplicationUserRole();
                    role.UserId = userId;
                    role.RoleAssigner = assigner;
                    role.RoleId = item;
                    context.AspNetUserRoles.Add(role);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return new IdentityResult() { };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new IdentityResult(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

That is a working example, using UserManager you can call it with definded
parameters like:

```
string[] roles = new string[] { /*your roles here*/ };
UserManager.AddToRole(/*UserIdHere*/, roles, /*assigerId here*/);
```

Similar to this you can implement async or other methods of UserManager.

Comment: Please read the whole question carefully..What I actually want is said in the ultimate para of my question!!

Comment: Thanks!! Where is additional property as parameter in AddToRole() Extension Method?? Please write the complete implementation of  AddToRole() method according to my code...Hope it will be more helpful for me!!

Comment: Now you have it with a specific example.

Comment: @TanvirArjel  Did you tried with exact example ? If it worked please mark it correct or give some feedback so other users with similar issue can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net core application in startup.cs you should inject proper store models

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, YOURROLEMODEL(ApplicationUserRole )>()
```

If you are using asp.net application there should be **IdentityConfig.cs** file You should implement your **UserStore** which will get you RoleModel as generic. You can see I have created **AppUserStore** class and it gets **MyIdentityRole** model as a generic Type. And changed ApplicationUserManager to use my **AppUserStore** class.

```
 public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new AppUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}

public class AppUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, MyIdentityRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AppUserStore(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class MyIdentityRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could not understand!! Would you explain me with an example please??

Comment: @TanvirArjel are you using asp.net core application?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I changed my answer to cover that case too

Comment: @TanvirArjel Sorry I didn' understand well question I showed how to replace your RoleModel instead of UserRoleModel, Now I will correct

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work!! What you write here is as same as my IdentityConfig.cs file code.So there is no problem...My Question is: Now How Can I Modify the AddToRoles() method which will also insert the additional property value into database along with UserID and RoleId.